# Groupby and shift a dask dataframe

Tags: python, dask

I would like to scale some operations I do on pandas dataframe using dask 2.14.
For example I would like to apply a shift on a column of a dataframe:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
data = dd.read_csv('some_file.csv')
data.set_index('column_A')
data['column_B'] = data.groupby(['column_A'])['column_B'].shift(-1)
```

but I get `AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'shift'`
I read the dask documentation   and I saw that there is not such a method (while there was in pandas)

Can you suggest some valid alternative?

Thank you

Comment: According to dask documentation Series object has a shift method. However, you are trying to apply it to a SeriesGroupBy object, that is returned when you are calling groupby method on a Series. groupby doesn't return a series! Series and SeriesGroupBy objects are not the same! In pandas it works in exactly the same way. All you need to do is reassign your desired series with updated data first, and then call shift on it.

Comment: thanks Karl. In pandas there is indeed a SeriesGroupBy method (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift)). I would like to shift just inside each  group)

Comment: My bad, however it doesn't change the fact that dask Dataframe columns are Series objects that have shift method but seriesgroupby objects don't. Is there any reason why you can't reassign your Series and you absolutely have to use it on a SeriesGroupBy? If so, I'm out of options to be honest, otherwise you could try this approach.

Comment: No bad here ;).  I thought about that but ff a use the shift method on a series some shifted element will ho in another group and that is no correct for me (I coud replace them with na or smtg though)

Comment: Could you explain why you're trying to shift items in column B? Also, may I assume that the order of the elements in the data frame is meaningful? without this, it seems that shift may result in meaningless results.

Comment: And one more question - how many values of A (groups) do you expect to have?

Comment: Hi Roy,
the order is  of course meaningful. The groups in column_A are about 200-250 while the total rows for each groups varies from group to group (I have a total of 50k rows).
The reason why I'm trying to shift items is that column B is a result of a formula that could be calculated very fast if done row by row but at the end I need to shift the results.
There are other methods to obtain the same column B but each one of them involve a reference to the previus row (within the group)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an [open ticket](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/4307) about this on GitHub. Essentially, you will have to use `apply` to get around it. I'm not sure whether this carries performance implications in `dask`. There is a further ticket referencing the issue and stating that it lies in `pandas`, but it's been open for some time.

This should be equivalent to the `pandas` operation:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list(range(10)),
                   'b': random.choices(['x', 'y'], k=10)})

print("####### PANDAS ######")
print("Initial df")
print(df.head(10))
print("................")

pandas_df = df.copy()
print("Final df")

pandas_df['a'] = pandas_df.groupby(['b'])['a'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1))

print(pandas_df.head(10))
print()


print("####### DASK ######")
print("Initial df")
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1).reset_index()
print(dask_df.head(10))
print("................")

dask_df['a'] = dask_df.groupby(['b'])['a'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1))

print("Final df")
print(dask_df.head(10))
```

I obviously can't benchmark the approach in `dask` since there seems to be no alternative. However, I can in `pandas`:

```
import string

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list(range(100000)),
                   'b': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), 100000)
                   })

def normal_way(df):
    df = df.groupby(['b'])['a'].shift(-1)

def apply_way(df):
    df = df.groupby(['b'])['a'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1))
```

The `timeit` results are:

```
%timeit normal_way(df)
4.25 ms ± 98 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit apply_way(df)
15 ms ± 446 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: thanks I wasn't so worried about performances since there is no alternative. I just needed an easy workaround right now. So thank you for you answer. Just for the record, I compared the timing of dask/groupby/apply/shift with the pandas/groupby/shift and it seems that the former lasts about twice longer than the latter (anyway is not a problem right now).

Comment: @LucaMonno I can't help but run to `timeit` when I see `apply` :) You're welcome for the answer. I've only ever tried `dask` the odd time just to see what it's about. IMO this is a pretty big wart in the API and I hope they're able to address it but progress seems slow. I wonder whether the release of Pandas 1.0 means it can be re-visited. I'll look into that separately